# Proyecto XCODE generado con Unity 5.3.4 se cierra cuando lo ejecuto en un IPAD2

Tags: ios, xcode, unity3d, iphone

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo un proyecto en XCODE generado con Unity 5.3.4. El problema es que se al ejecutarlo en un iPad2 se cierra al instante. Al ejecutarlo en mi iphone 5 funciona bien. Ambos dispositivos tienen iOS 9.2.

Adjunto el log que me reporta en el iPad2:

```
2016-04-25 16:31:43.619 catalogo[1316:49656] -> registered mono modules 0xdcf090
2016-04-25 16:31:44.019 catalogo[1316:49656] You've implemented -[<UIApplicationDelegate> application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:], but you still need to add "remote-notification" to the list of your supported UIBackgroundModes in your Info.plist.
-> applicationDidFinishLaunching()
-> applicationDidBecomeActive()
Renderer: PowerVR SGX 543
Vendor:   Imagination Technologies
Version:  OpenGL ES 2.0 IMGSGX543-124.1
GLES:     2
GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap GL_OES_mapbuffer GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_debug_label GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_EXT_draw_instanced GL_EXT_instanced_arrays GL_EXT_map_buffer_range GL_EXT_occlusion_query_boolean GL_EXT_pvrtc_sRGB GL_EXT_read_format_bgra GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch GL_EXT_shader_texture_lod GL_EXT_shadow_samplers GL_EXT_sRGB GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_texture_rg GL_EXT_texture_storage GL_APPLE_clip_distance GL_APPLE_color_buffer_packed_float GL_APPLE_copy_texture_levels GL_APPLE_framebuffer_multisample GL_APPLE_rgb_422 GL_APPLE_sync GL_APPLE_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_APPLE_texture_max_level GL_APPLE_texture_packed_float GL_IMG_read_format GL_IMG_texture_comp
ression_pvrtc 
OPENGL LOG: Creating OpenGL ES 2.0 graphics device
Initialize engine version: 5.3.4f1 (fdbb5133b820)
```

Comment: No conozco mucho de este entorno, pero me parece que el mensaje te explica el problema: *You've implemented `-[<UIApplicationDelegate> application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:]`, but you still need to add "remote-notification" to the list of your supported UIBackgroundModes in your Info.plist*

Comment: Que config tienes en tus exports?

Comment: Actualicé mi post con la un screenshot , reitero solo me pasa con el ipad2 en un iphone 5 funciona bien

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que te dice el log , es que has de permitir las notificaciones remotas en background indicándolo en el .plist de tu proyecto.

Seguramente si quieres estar seguro si es eso si quitas el método `[<UIApplicationDelegate> application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:]`
y cualquier otro que este relacionado con las notifications , te funcionaria.